# Trouble having filter method working for my flatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, filter, react-native-flatlist

I've been trying to filter out the name of the item user has entered and tell them that the item has been found, If the item isnt there, then the user should be alerted that too, but I don't know for some reason my filter method doesn't seem to be working. This is the flatList I've right now.

```
const data = [
  {
    groceryItem: 'Apple',
    price: '$2.99',
    category: 'Produce',
    src: require('./assets/apples.jpg'),
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
  },
  {
    groceryItem: 'Pear',
    price: '$2.49',
    category: 'Produce',
    src: require('./assets/pear.jpg'),
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
  }]
```

This is the code I've to search the item in the list. NameInput is the user input, set to what the user has entered.

```
 const [nameInput, setNameInput] = useState('');
 const [itemsList, setItemsList] = useState(data); //storing data items temporarily

 const searchItem = () => {
    if (nameInput == "") {
      Alert.alert("At least an input is empty.");
    } 
    else if (itemsList.filter(itemFound)) {
      Alert.alert("Item " + nameInput + " has been found." + '\n' + 'You want to add it in the list?'+"\n"+"If, yes click on the modal below.");
    }
  };


function itemFound(item) {
  if (item.groceryItem == nameInput ) {
    return item;
  }else{
    Alert.alert(nameInput +" isn't available. Sorry!");
  }
}
```

Later when the button is clicked the user should be alerted if the item is present or not in the list.
I don't know what I'm missing to make my filter method work here. If anyone could help me with this, it would be greatful.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return **item** inside the filter function.
It returns `true` or `false`. Filter returns a new (filtered) array on its own.

Try to find a product like so:

```
const searchItem = () => {
    if (nameInput === "") {
        Alert.alert("At least an input is empty.");
    } 
    else if (itemFound()) {
        Alert.alert("Item " + nameInput + " has been found." + '\n' + 'You want to add it in the list?'+"\n"+"If, yes click on the modal below.");
    }
};

function itemFound() {
    for (let item of itemsList) {
        if (item.groceryItem === nameInput)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see whether the item is in the list you can use `Array.some`
This will return `true` if found, or `false` if not found.

If you want to access the relevant object, you can use `Array.find` which will either return the object or `undefined`. Whereas `Array.filter` will return an array with all matching objects, `find` will return the first one found so it depends what you want to do

```
const searchItem = () => {
    const itemFound = itemsList.some(item => item.groceryName === nameInput);

    if (nameInput == "") {
      Alert.alert("At least an input is empty.");
    } else if (itemFound) {
      Alert.alert("Item " + nameInput + " has been found." + '\n' + 'You want to add it in the list?'+"\n"+"If, yes click on the modal below.");
    } else {
      Alert.alert("not found..."
    }
  };
```